# How to use NSCollectionView and Outlets properly?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

I'm desperately trying to connect controls of NSViews which will reside in a NSCollectionView using outlets. The collection view is fed using an NSArrayController.

I created the NSView in a separate NIB file and in the implementation of NSCollectionViewItem I overwrote copyWithZone to load it:

```
    -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id result = [super copyWithZone:zone];

    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"InputView" owner:result];

    return result;
}
```

I've used this approach according to this [instructions](http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/72).

Unfortunately this is what happening:

[image]

The NSView looks like this:

[image]

The NSCollectionView resides in a NSScrollView and the scrollbar is set to enable automatically. 
But as you can see there's no scrollbar.

I don't really understand what I need to do so the NSCollectionView knows the dimensions of its NSViews.

It has worked before when I didn't have a seperate NIB-file, but then I couldn't make outlet connections from the view to the item :-(

Comment: The instructions link is broken.

Comment: Well, it's a pretty old post. I wrote something about it over here that might help you though: http://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/nscollectionview-tutorial-for-dummies-xcode-3-1-3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many item are in the array controller? Your output looks correct for what you've described, assuming there are at least 14 things in the controller (1 view per item). The sizing is just off. It's not clear which problem you're trying to solve.

Perhaps you were looking for a grid, and so need to call `setMaximumNumberOfColumns:`? Or perhaps your views aren't being resized as you expect (check `-maxItemSize` and `-minItemSize`)?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the NSCollectionView resides in a NSScrollView and the scrollbar is set to enable automatically.

But as you can see there's no scrollbar. I don't really understand what I need to do so the NSCollectionView knows the size of its NSViews.

I hope I made may problem a little clearer.

Comment: +1. Yes, if you are not getting the layout you expect, you definitely need to call setMinItemSize: and/or setMaxItemSize:. If the minItemSize is {0, 0}, then the collection view will attempt to put all of the views in the visible area and it won't scroll.

Comment: In IB, you can also try turning off the autoresizing springs and struts. I think NSCollectionView uses those as hints to figure out what the default minItemSize and maxItemSize settings should be. If you turn off autoresizing, I'd imagine NSCollectionView would keep the items the same size as the view in IB.

Comment: Thanks kperryua. I just gave that a try, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.
Seems like one has no other choice but to set the minItemSize.